# StreamBuilder is not reacting when calling StreamController.sink.add

Tags: dart, flutter, stream, bloc, stream-builder

I have a screen in my Flutter app dedicated to editing a list of objects. When you press the edit button a modal pops up, allowing you to edit the objects values. When you close the model the list is refreshed through a BLoC. However, when calling the method that refreshes the list, nothing happens.

```
bloc.dart
```

```dart
class Bloc {

  final _provider = ModelProvider();
  final _controller = StreamController<List<Model>>();

  Stream<List<Model>> get models => _controller.stream;

  void getModels() async {
    final List<Model> models = await _provider.readAll();
    _controller.sink.add(models);
  }

  Future<int> saveModel(Model model) async {
    final int id = await _provider.write(model);
    return id;
  }

}
```

```
list_screen.dart
```

```dart
class ListScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final bloc = Bloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          // SliverAppBar ...
          StreamBuilder<List<Model>>(
            stream: bloc.models,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                        onPressed: () => _editModel(context),
                      ),
                ),
              } else {
                bloc.getModels();
                return Container();
              }
            }          
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _editModel(BuildContext context) async {
    final Model edited = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => EditModal(),
    );
    if (edited != null) {
      await bloc.saveModel(edited);
      bloc.getModels();
    }
  }

}
```

I know that the data is being stored in the database correctly, because if I go to the previous screen and then return to the editing screen the data is updated. Can anyone help me figure out why the `StreamBuilder` is not rebuilding?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm just getting into Flutter development and experiencing this exact issue.

Comment: I never resolved this issue. I switched to Provider for state management, but that was easy for me because I was in the early stages of development.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you don't put the await when calls bloc.getModels after save or the save method is giving an error and break the method not running the getModels

Comment: Using `await` with `Bloc.getModels` won't work because it doesn't return a `Future`, and I know the data is being stored correctly because I can print `models` in `Bloc.getModels` and see that it fetches the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone: For me the problem, was that while I was updating the List it was the actually the same reference that was stored in a field. Creating a new list each time and not storing the list in the same field resolved it. We can't see inside your ModelProvider from the question but it looks like it could be the same issue.

**This did not update after the first time:**

```
class MiniaturePaintsBloc implements Bloc {

  List<MiniaturePaint> _miniaturePaints;

  final _controller = StreamController<List<MiniaturePaint>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<MiniaturePaint>> get miniaturePaintsStream => _controller.stream;

  void fetchMiniaturePaints() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection("MiniaturePaints").getDocuments(source: Source.serverAndCache);
    _miniaturePaints = querySnapshot.documents.map((doc) => _docToMiniaturePaint(doc)).toList();
    _controller.sink.add(_miniaturePaints);
  }

  //rest of BloC code here
}
```

**By removing the field, it now updates the StreamBuilder:**

```
class MiniaturePaintsBloc implements Bloc {

  final _controller = StreamController<List<MiniaturePaint>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<MiniaturePaint>> get miniaturePaintsStream => _controller.stream;

  void fetchMiniaturePaints() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection("MiniaturePaints").getDocuments(source: Source.serverAndCache);
    List<MiniaturePaint> miniaturePaints = querySnapshot.documents.map((doc) => _docToMiniaturePaint(doc)).toList();
    _controller.sink.add(miniaturePaints);
  }

  //rest of BLoC code here
}
```

Comment: This is technically doing the EXACT same thing. No difference what-so-ever.
You're changing the _miniaturePaints list to a different list in both code snippets. The fact that one is a field makes no difference because it's the data we want, not whether it's a field or variable.